# Term of partially ordered set with "levels"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, order-theory

Suppose that we have a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$ such that the following condition holds:

There exists a disjoint partition $X = \bigcup_{ i \in \mathbb N_0 } X_i$ such that
for $i < j$ we have $ \forall x \in X_i, y \in X_j : x_i < x_j$.

The principal example is of course any simplicial complex, where the $X_i$ correspond to simplices of dimension $i$.

So a partially ordered set with "levels" is a very common structure. What is the canonical term (there should be one) for such a structure?

Comment: Do you require that $X_i$ is an antichain?

Comment: Not necessarily, although in the application I have in mind, the sets $X_i$ are antichains. Thanks for making me aware of that.